# How does Python order strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, comparison, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I've so far discovered that in Python: 
`[space] < 0-9 < A-Z < a-z` 
when ordering strings.

But why is it that `'[space] a'` < `'a'`?　
And why is it that `'abc'` > `'ABCDEFG'`?

How are strings ordered in Python? 
Is there a flowchart that will help me understand this process?

Comment: You shouldn't really be surprised by facts 2 and 3 because they follow immediately from fact 1.

Comment: second time I close such a question today with same target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings of the same type are ordered naively, with lower byte values or code points ordered before higher byte values or code points.

Comment: My question is which characters have higher byte values?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart

Comment: So when comparing two strings such as `'[space] a'` and `'a'` what values are actually being compared? Why is the former less than the latter?

Comment: Because the former is 0x20 and the latter is 0x61.

Comment: `'[space]'` is 0x20, so how is `'[space] a'` also 0x20?

Comment: The string itself is more than the one character, but the comparison is complete as soon as the first character is compared.